# Function doesn't produce output

Tags: php

I am not getting any error when running this code:

```
function CheckLogin()
{       
   if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
   $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar(); 

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}

function GetLoginSessionVar()
{
    $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
    $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
    echo "$retvar";

    return $retvar;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do that it is not doing? Also how are you calling `CheckLogin()`

Comment: You are using `$this->$this->GetLoginSessionVar()` Just checking, is it actually in a class? You have not made that clear from your snippet!

Comment: It is supposed to perform Login in my code. may be its not clear from my code.  yes GetLoginSessionVar() is in my class

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with how the code runs so I guess it must be how you are using it.

I created a dummy class from the little you showed us and it works fine when used like this

```
class muppet {

    protected $rand_key = 'kermit';

    function CheckLogin()
    {
       if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
       $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

         if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
         {
            return false;
         }
         return true;
    }

    function GetLoginSessionVar()
    {
        $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
        $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
        echo "$retvar";

        return $retvar;
    }
}
```

If you run this like this

```
$login = new muppet();
$areWeLoggedIn = $login->CheckLogin();

echo $areWeLoggedIn ? 'Logged In' : 'Not Logged In';
```

You should see the message `Not logged In`:

If you run it like this, I am creating a user account to make it look like I am logged in here!!!

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usr_d1798f4110'] = 'Im Free';

$login = new muppet();
$areWeLoggedIn = $login->CheckLogin();

echo $areWeLoggedIn ? ' Logged In' : ' Not Logged In';
```

You should see the `Logged In` message.